# MISRA warning 12.6 when multiple compiler swich definitions are checked with #if

Tags: c, c-preprocessor, conditional-compilation, misra

If there is a code applicable on more than 1 project / variant than we use pre-processor switches (compiler switches) to enable or disable the code. For example if MACRO1, MACRO2 and MACRO3 are preprocessor directives or compiler switches in a project than

```
#if (defined MACRO1 || defined MACRO2)
/* Do something */
#elif (defined MACRO2 && defined MACRO3) 
/* Do something */
#else
/* Do something */
#endif
```

This conditional #if statement yields MISRA warning 12.6 as 
"boolean expression required for operator: '!'; the -strong(B,...) option can help provide Boolean-by-enforcement"

Can someone please tell me if there is an alternate way to write this conditional statement or how to justify it?

Comment: I See no "operator !"; is it perhaps in one of the macros? The general complaint is when you apply a logical operator to an int, like in `!0`.

Comment: That warning isn't caused by the compiler switches but by something else in the code.

Comment: There is nothing MISRA non-compliant in the code as shown...